# Problem with running PHP and Node.js on same server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, apache2

I am trying to run Node.js with socket.io on the same server. We have a small tool which allows users to test their websockets which you can find in [here](https://www.101toolbox.com/live-socket-emit). Now the problem is that its not connecting with domain for example if ill use the original ip https://123.23.23.12:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NIHXfZI (disclosing real ip for sake of confidentiality) it connects to the socket.io but when i use https://www.101toolbox.com:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NIHXfZI it just wouldn't connect. Now i tried to create reverse proxy and other stuff but it didn't worked either, the server is using laravel with some node js which are run by pm2, please note that they worked before moving the website to the new hosting without using any special apache2 configuration. Heres the apache2 configuration, i am literally out of ideas.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName 101toolbox.com
        ServerAlias www.101toolbox.com *.101toolbox.com 101toolbox.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/101toolbox/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/101toolbox_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/101toolbox_access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/101toolbox>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/101toolbox.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/101toolbox.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the correct configuration for apache2 which made the node apps work. It turns out i should register 2 different proxies for socket.io.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

    ServerName 101toolbox.com
    ServerAlias www.101toolbox.com *.101toolbox.com 101toolbox.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/101toolbox/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/101toolbox_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/101toolbox_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/101toolbox>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off 
    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyPass /node https://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /node https://127.0.0.1:3000

    ProxyPass /sockets https://127.0.0.1:3001
    ProxyPassReverse /sockets https://127.0.0.1:3001
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass   /socket.io https://127.0.0.1:3001/socket.io
    ProxyPassReverse /socket.io https://127.0.0.1:3001/socket.io

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/101toolbox.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/101toolbox.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes? I have tried this on liveserver and it worked fine